# How to delegate "delete" operation to another Model in Cakephp4?

Tags: php, model, cakephp-4.x

I have 2 Models (`SuperRubriques` and `CustomRubriques`) using the same table `rubriques` in DB.

When I delete from `SuperRubriques`, I would like to delegate the delete to `CustomRubriques` (as `CustomRubriques` has a `hasOne` association  with `extended_rubriques` that `SuperRubriques` doesn't know).

For info, the `rubriques` table in DB has the field `model` containing `'CustomRubriques'` (i.e. the Model with which it has been saved).

I've tried to do it in `SuperRubriquesTable::beforeDete()` :

```
// In SuperRubriquesTable.php
public function beforeDelete(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
{
    $table = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get($entity->model); // $entity->model contains 'CustomRubriques'
    $rubriqueEntity = $table->get($entity->id);
    return $table->delete($rubriqueEntity);
}
```

However `$table->delete($rubriqueEntity)` is `true` (when I debug) but the record is not deleted in DB, I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix the issue :
Instead of deleguating inside `SuperRubriquesTable::beforeDelete()`, I've done the job in `SuperRubriquesController::delete()` :

```
// In SuperRubriquesController
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    $rubrique = $this->SuperRubriques->get($id);

    $rubriqueModel = $rubrique->model;// contains 'CustomRubriques'
    $this->loadModel($rubriqueModel);
    $rubriqueEntity = $this->$rubriqueModel->get($id);
    
    if ($this->$rubriqueModel->delete($rubriqueEntity)) {
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```